# exporting SAS output using proc export to an excel with existing headers

Tags: excel, sas, export

I want to export SAS output using proc export to an excel with existing headers.  So the output from the table has its own headers but I want to export without headers and use the headers of the excel template. What is the best way to do this?

```
Proc export data=ALL_Shipping
      dbms=xlsx
      outfile=&dpath./&template.xlsx"
      replace;
      putnames=no;
      Sheet='ShippingRecord';
  run;
```

Comment: Don't even try to do this. Export it to a new sheet and in the sheet with the pretty headers reference the values from the sheet written by SAS.

Comment: It's not even possible to export to a specific row. The import allows you to specify a range to read data from a sheet, but that option doesn't exist in export.